# Find or create an element in a linked list, without loosing the head

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to use a static linked list of a structure that contains a data element, an id element and the next element in a function.
My function is called with an id, if there's an element with this id in the linked list, I have to return it to use it later. If there isn't, I have to create it at the end of the list and return it too.
This is performed with a function called lstforc

The problem is that when I give my linked list to the lstforc function with a new id, it seems to not append the element at the end of my linked list.

I tried several solutions by myself but either the element isn't added to the end of the list, either the element is added but I'm losing the head of my linked list.

Here's my structure for my linked list :

```c
typedef struct          s_list_fd
{
    int                 fd;
    char                *mem;
    struct s_list_fd    *next;
}                       t_list_fd;
```

Here's the function called several time in the program, where I initialize my static linked list :

```c
int         get_next_line(int id)
{
    static t_list_fd    *mfd_s = NULL;
    t_list_fd           *mfd_c;

    print_list(mfd_s);
    if (!(mfd_c = ft_lstforc_fd(&mfd_s, id)))
        return (-1);
        //I have to use mfd_c later in the program
    return (0);
}
```

Here's my function that either return the good element, either create a new one with the correct id (don't add the element at the end):

```c
t_list_fd   *ft_lstforc_fd(t_list_fd **lst, int id)
{
    t_list_fd *tmp;

    tmp = *lst;
    while (tmp)
    {
        if (tmp->id == id)
            return (tmp);
        tmp = (*lst)->next;
    }
    if (!(tmp = (t_list_fd *)malloc(sizeof(t_list_fd))))
        return (NULL);
    tmp->id = id;
    tmp->mem = NULL;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return (tmp);
}
```

Here's the same function (well appending the element at the end, but losing the linked list head) :

```c
t_list_fd   *ft_lstforc_fd(t_list_fd **lst, int id)
{
    while (*lst)
    {
        if ((*lst)->id == id)
            return (*lst);
        *lst = (*lst)->next;
    }
    if (!(*lst = (t_list_fd *)malloc(sizeof(t_list_fd))))
        return (NULL);
    (*lst)->id = id;
    (*lst)->mem = NULL;
    (*lst)->next = NULL;
    return (*lst);
}
```

Comment: To append an element, you need to create a link from element N-1 to element N with *next pointer. This is what's missing because in you are using while(*lst), if you use while((*lst)->next), you'll stop your while loop at the last element. Then you can allocate a new one and link it via (*lst)->next = new_element. Please note that you should use calloc instead of malloc to be sure your new element is well set to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function is almost good, but you don't make use of the fact that `lst` is a pointer to a node pointer. You only ever access it as `*lst` and `*lst` is always `mfd_s` in `get_next_line`. That is why you think you lose your head: You append the new node to the riginal head, thereby losing all other nodes.

When you iterate through the list, you do two things: Check for existing ids and trying to find the end of the list, where you want to append the new node. The id is checked correctly. In order to find the end of the list, you must update `lst`, not `*lst`. Change

```
    *lst = (*lst)->next;
```

to

```
    lst = &(*lst)->next;
```

Isn't that the same? No. Consider an empty list. Now you want to append a node. At first, `lst == &mfd_s` and assigning to `*lst` will update the list head. Append another node with a different id. You begin with `lst == &mfd_s`, but `lst` is updated in the while loop, so that it is now pointing to the next pointer of the first node. Asigning to `*lst` will update that next pointer, not the head.

This is a useful technique, because the extra level of indirection means that the head node is not a special case. (That's what you would have to do to fix your first function: Make adding the first node a special case, where you update `*lst`, then treat the other case, but keep a `prev` pointer, so that after exhausting the list, you know what the last vistied node was, whose `next` you should update.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly ! I was confused with this notion